# flutter true time plugin not working with flutter build Error compilereleasejavawithjavac

Tags: flutter

This error is raised when I try to build APK and using `flutter_true_time`

```
could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compilereleasejavawithjavac'. 
   > could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releasecompileclasspath'. 
      > could not find com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library-extension-rx:3.4. 
      required by: 
           project :app > tv.orale.truetime:true_time_release:1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin needs to be migrated with AndroidX and change compileSdkVersion to 28.

So I resolved it myself by forked it to my GitHub, change what it needs, and then use it in pub.yaml.

Anyone can add these line, and it will work.

```yaml
true_time:
    git: https://github.com/ShadyBoshra2012/flutter_true_time.git
```

Hope it helps someone.